# Spring boot application exe file

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Is there any way to create the exe file of spring boot application executable jar? I've used launch maven plugin but exe file which it's creation is not working. On double click it doesn't show application Console....

Comment: Try with GraalVM (native-image)... ?

Comment: @Sandy, Were you able to prepare the EXE file for your Spring boot application? I am looking for similar stuff for my Spring boot web project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Launch4J:

https://genuinecoder.com/convert-java-jar-to-exe/

1. Download Launch4J: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/
2. Select your .jar and the output for your .exe
   [image: launch4j]
3. Select additional details, for example an Icon. Most basic configs speak for themself.
4. Include classpaths:
   [image: launch4j]
5. Aditonally select the required java version in the JRE tab.
6. Build the .exe!

--

Although in your case if you just want to run the .jar I would look at my other comment first and run it with
`java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar`

Comment: Can you extend you answer. External resources tend to rust over time it is better have at least core answer here.

Comment: Will do, give me a few mins!